# Booking conflicts using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, filemaker

Need some advice. Trying to build a booking system integrated into our other systems and its all done apart from reliably detecting conflicts of other bookings

My booking database structure is quite simple as follows

```
fk_ResourceID, StartDate, EndDate, z_TimeStart, z_TimeEnd
```

I have a query that fetches the data and retrieves resources booked within a date range. This works great. I now need to add another filter which checks for time as well.

```
SELECT

   fk_ResourceID, 
   z_TimeStart, 
   z_TimeEnd,
   StartDate,
   EndDate

FROM Resources 

WHERE fk_ResourceID = 'Drama Room' 

AND 
(
    (StartDate <= ? AND EndDate >= ?) OR
    (StartDate <= ? AND EndDate >= ?) OR
    (StartDate >= ? AND EndDate <= ?)
)

ORDER BY fk_ResourceID ASC
```

I couldn't figure out how to include the time check so what I did was loop through the each record from the query and check against this criteria

```
If(
    (z_TimeStart >= new_booking_start_time  and z_TimeStart <= new_booking_end_time) 
or
    (new_booking_start_time  >= z_TimeStart and new_booking_start_time <= z_TimeEnd); 

True )
```

I thought it was working, but unfortunately I've come across a scenario where it fails. The data I have is below.

```
Returned Data From SQL Query: 'Drama Room','08:55','23:55','07/22/2016','07/28/2016'
Data Input in my form to check: 'Drama Room','08:05','08:35','07/24/2016','07/24/2016'
```

Is there a fairly simple way to implement a time search in the original sql query, before I start hacking my conditional statement in the loop to check for dates as well as time? Im using a combination of FileMaker sql and scripts commands to try and resolve this. The ? is a query parameter in FM SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct logic to get conflicts

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Resources r
WHERE r.fk_ResourceID = 'Drama Room' AND
      r.StartDate <= $EndDate AND
      r.EndDate >= $StartDate
ORDER BY r.fk_ResourceID ASC;
```